# Unable to start fluentD (td-agent)

Tags: rubygems, centos7, fluentd, efk, td-agent

I have installed fluentD(td-agent) version 2 in CentOs 7. Now I'm unable to start td-agent. While starting td-agent it was throwing some error

> -- Unit td-agent.service has begun starting up. Feb 02 14:53:39 chninitefk01 fluentd[2282]:
>   /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:271:in
>   `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem fluentd (>= 0.a)
>   (Gem::GemNotFoundException) Feb 02 14:53:39 chninitefk01
>   fluentd[2282]: from
>   /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:299:in`
>   activate_bin_path' Feb 02 14:53:39 chninitefk01 fluentd[2282]: from
>   /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `' Feb 02 14:53:39
>   chninitefk01 systemd[1]: td-agent.service: control process exited,
>   code=exited status=1 Feb 02 14:53:39 chninitefk01 systemd[1]: Failed
>   to start td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data.
>   -- Subject: Unit td-agent.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd

I have tried to install fluentD gem using `td-agent-gem install fluentD`, but that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Try running td-agent in dry run mode `td-agent --dry-run`. It will give you an idea what's wrong. It could be an issue of permissions.
Has the plugin installed? you can check with `/usr/sbin/td-agent-gem list`. Check if it's installed.

Update: You do not need to install fluentd gem, it's already there. The probable cause could be permissions, running with non-sudo while installed as one or ruby.

Answer (score -1):

Because of systemd, the following might work :

```
$ sudo systemctl start td-agent
$ sudo systemctl status td-agent
```